# Conditional Columns In @Entity class In Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, entity

I am facing issues in handling conditional columns inside `@Entity` class in REFCURSORS in Hibernate. We have a requirement where in, as per the inputs some columns might not be returned at all in the REFCURSORS. So in such scenarios the query execution (`@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`) gives 'Invalid Column Name' since that column doesn't get returned only. Any ideas on how to handle this scenario?

For example in the following entity class column3 will not always be returned by the refcursor of the stored proc. In such scenario my stored proc query execution gives me Invalid Column Name. So how can we make column3 optional?

```
@Entity
public class Cursor1Response {

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "column_name_1") 
    private Date column1;

    @Column(name = "column_name_2") 
    private Double column2; 

    // This column gets returned under only some conditions 
    // else it won't be returned as a part of the stored proc refcursor response
    @Column(name = "column_name_3") 
    private Double column3; 
}
```

Comment: Entites are not for dynamic data structures. Use DTO projection https://thoughts-on-java.org/dto-projections/

Comment: Within DTO projection also we need to specify the fields we have to read as a result of the query which we provide. But these fields in itself are optional and vary according to multiple conditions. Hence net net it will be the same challenge.

Comment: Then JPA is probably not the right tool. Do you know https://www.jooq.org/